# Are Reverse Debuggers Impossible on OSX?

Tags: debugging, osx

I have been impressed with the reverse debugging (that is stepping back in time through a program) capabilities in GDB and tools like QIRA, but I am a little confused as to why no such program exists for the OSX platform (GDS does not support reverse debugging on OSX.) Is there a technical reason why a reverse debugger is not possible on OSX? I would imagine that under the same architectures the task of implementing a time oblivious debugger would be almost exactly the same. Why would porting to OSX be a impossible or difficult? I mostly assume there is a technical challenge here because no one has implemented such an obviously useful program.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, the stock reversible debugging support in gdb is not all that useful. It's *really* slow (because it records individual instructions), so you generally have to turn it on just for a critical piece of the program. I don't know of very many people that use it, which may explain why it hasn't been ported widely. I'm not familiar with QIRA's implementation so I don't know what the reasons would be there.

Something like [Mozilla's `rr`](https://github.com/mozilla/rr) can be a lot faster, because it records at the system call boundary. But that's much more tied to the specific OS, so it's a lot of work to reimplement for another platform.

One last possibility is something whole-system, that records hardware events and so would be OS-agnostic by default. But then you have to run a full OS to record/replay one program, so this may not be very attractive either. This is the route that [PANDA](https://github.com/moyix/panda) and some [experimental QEMU patches](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2015-09/msg04623.html) take (note that PANDA doesn't actually support the gdb reverse-step instructions yet, but it could be implemented).